# Is it possible to determine if an object is being referenced by another object?

Tags: c#

I have a memory leak in my C# program and cannot determine who is holding the reference to my object. Is there a way at runtime to determine which objects are holding a reference to a specific object?

In this economy my budget is zero, so a native or free solution is my only choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [.NET Memory Profiler](http://memprofiler.com/).  They have a 14 day free trial (so your budget is safe).  Excerpt from the features page ...

> For a managed type instance the
>   following additional information is
>   presented:
>
> - References from and to the instance

Per comments: Agree 100% ... well worth the very reasonable license fee.

Comment: I've used this many times and it is really a great tool. Well worth the licence fee.

Comment: @adrianbanks: I used it too, and I agree with you.

Answer (score 3):

For a free tool take a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/ricom/archive/2004/12/10/279612.aspx).  This article discusses how to use the free tools from MS (windbg/sos) to find memory leaks in managed code.  The interface is not pretty, but it gets the job done.  Here is a link to [windbg](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/Debugging/debugstart.mspx).

Answer (score 1):

I learned how to debug memory leak issues from here
http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2008/03/17/net-debugging-demos-lab-6-memory-leak.aspx

using the debugging tools for windows

the learning curve is pretty steep, but once you get it, it's a great skill to have